# select specific field in each joined table in LINQ sql query entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

```
 public class OnLoginData
 {
     public List<TableDetails> lstTableDetails { get; set; }
     public List<CategoryDetails> lstCategoryDetails { get; set; }       
 }

 public class TableDetails
 {
     public int TableId { get; set; }
     public int TableNumber { get; set; }
     public string TableName { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class CategoryDetails
 {
     public int CategoryId { get; set; }
     public string CategoryName { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string Image { get; set; }
     public long? SystemId { get; set; }
     public int? SortId { get; set; }
 }

 var queryLoginAdimin = from admin in conDb.SystemAdminMasters
                        join system in conDb.SystemMasters on admin.SystemID equals system.SystemId into SM
                        join category in conDb.MenuCategoryMasters on admin.SystemID equals category.SystemId into CM
                        join menu in conDb.MenuMasters on admin.SystemID equals menu.SystemId into MM
                        join table in conDb.TableMasters on admin.SystemID equals table.SystemId into TM
                        select new OnLoginData
                        {
                            lstTableDetails = TM.Select(o => new 
                            {
                                o.TableId,
                                o.TableName,
                                o.TableNumber 
                            }).ToList()
                        };
```

Please check the above code, I'm trying to do joins using multiple tables and I don't require all fields from database tables. I only need those fields where I have take a separate class `TableDetails` and `CategoryDetails`. I want to select those fields from above linq query and create a whole List that is On LoginData.

How do I do that?

Comment: you can use mappers like Automapper that they have ProjeTo Mehtod for do this

Answer (score 0):

You Can Query in Below Way

```
var queryLoginAdimin =
   from admin in conDb.SystemAdminMasters
   join system in conDb.SystemMasters on admin.SystemID equals system.SystemId into SM
   join category in conDb.MenuCategoryMasters on admin.SystemID equals category.SystemId into CM
   join menu in conDb.MenuMasters on admin.SystemID equals menu.SystemId into MM
   select new OnLoginData
   {
       lstTableDetails = conDb.TableMasters
                              .Where(table => table.SystemId == admin.SystemID)
                              .Select(o => new TableDetails
                               {
                                   TableId = o.TableId,
                                   TableName = o.TableName,
                                   TableNumber = o.TableNumber
                               }),
       //Same for lstCategoryDetails
    };
```

You Can't use .ToList() inside select so  you can change OnLoginData To IEnumerable

```
    public class OnLoginData
    {
        public IEnumerable<TableDetails> lstTableDetails { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CategoryDetails> lstCategoryDetails { get; set; }    
    }
```

Comment: thank you Anand, but unfortunately it gives me error say
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<QuizzrApi.Controllers.QuizzrController.TableDetails>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
i tried everything bro

Comment: Updated the .Select for lstTableDetails. Pls see the edited answer

Comment: Anand , thank you so much . it worked. the old one only worked . 
i dont know what was problem first select was causing error, and now its now. Both categorydetails and tabledetails are IEnumerable according to your given code

Comment: thanks for help . all working , but im concerned about one thing, that when i see the query created by linq, they are huge and big . using union all everywhere and its very complex i hope that is normal it wont harm  server or memory . Im new into entity framework and linq queries.
Or should i create Stored procedure and call it using entity framework ?